# Leap Motion and Cocos2d (Xcode), displaying images on device connect/disconnect?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, leap-motion

I'm in the process of porting my Cocos2D game to Leap Motion. I have the controls implemented but part of the submission guidelines dictate that you must give visual indication when the device is connected or not connected.

The part of the Leap code which tells you the device is disconnected is this (I've added some custom code which I'm having problems with, only the NSLog is there as standard):

`- (void)onDisconnect:(NSNotification *)notification`
{

```
    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    CGSize winSize = [director winSize];

CCSprite *connect1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[AssetHelper getDeviceSpecificFileNameFor:@"connecttest.png"]];
connect1.position = CGPointMake(winSize.width / 2, winSize.height / 2);
[self addChild:background2 z:2];


    NSLog(@"Disconnected");
```

`}`

If I start the app everything works fine but disconnecting the Leap doesn't show up the image. The Z position is correct and I know the function works because I see "Disconnected in the log" and if I replace the CCSprite code with a terminate application function the game quits.

I've also tried replacing the code with a scene load. Removing the controller will push to another scene but it's not the most elegant solution, also it won't do it on start up.

I suspect it could be a timing thing whereby the image appears then disappears really quickly.

I really have no idea. What I need to happen is for the image to appear when the device is disconnected and then disappear when reconnected.

Any clues?

Comment: So the Leap Motion part of this is working fine? I was going to say that (at least during the beta period) the disconnection events are suppressed if you're running this in the debugger within Xcode, but it seems like you're getting those events just fine.

Comment: Indeed, having spoken to a few of the support people at Leap they think it could be a bug on the Objective-C implementation side but they've suggested something else I can try whereby the onDisconnect call isn't being called correctly. I'll give it a try soon and report back I just need some sleep first.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is embarrassing, it was something really simple, but I'm blaming sleep deprivation ;-)

All you have to do is query `[controller isConnected]` when initialising the controller. I never did find any reference to it in the SDK though.

My full block of code is here if anyone needs it.

`- (void)onInit:(NSNotification *)notification`
{
 `NSLog(@"Initialized");`

```
if([controller isConnected])
{
    CCLayer *layer = [CCLayer node];
    CCSprite *label = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[AssetHelper getDeviceSpecificFileNameFor:@"connecttest2.png"]];
    [layer addChild:label];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setNotificationNode:layer];
    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    CGSize winSize = [director winSize];
    layer.position = CGPointMake(winSize.width / 2, winSize.height / 2);
} else {


    CCLayer *layer = [CCLayer node];
    CCSprite *label = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[AssetHelper getDeviceSpecificFileNameFor:@"connecttest.png"]];
    [layer addChild:label];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setNotificationNode:layer];
    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    CGSize winSize = [director winSize];
    layer.position = CGPointMake(winSize.width - (winSize.width * 0.5), winSize.height - (winSize.height * 0.90));

}
```

`}`

As it's a global CCLayer node it doesn't seem to respond to any removal methods so what I've done is repeated the same code again in the onConnected method and switched the disconnected image for a 1x1 transparent pixel once the device is recognised.

Not the nicest hack but it does the job quite nicely.